# EF Core extending model with migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an existing database that was created with code-first approach

Now I'd want to add an another property to my model, but after running app and trying to work on that data EF Core says that

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'test'.'

That's reasonable, so I'm removing that property (test), creating migration, adding that property (test) once again, creating another migration and updating model

But now:

> There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.

How can I extend my db schema with code first without losing my data?

Comment: Do you have to deploy this schema change to the public, or is the database local to your organization?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes

Comment: Not sure if we're at cross-purposes here, but if this is a single, centralized database that is shared amongst all of the clients, you don't need migrations; just remote in and make the change manually.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yea, changing manually db was probably the easiest solution, thanks :P